# Pythonic way to modify python path relative to current directory

Tags: filesystems, python, filepath

I have a project that is structured like this (cut down a lot to give the gist)...

```
State_Editor/
    bin/
    state_editor/
        __init__.py
        main.py
        features/
            __init__.py
            # .py files
        io/
            __init__.py
            # .py files
        # etc.
```

You get the idea. Now say for example that `foobar.py` in `features` did this... `from state_editor.io.fileop import subInPath`. Obviously `State_Editor` needs to be in the path.

I've read about sys.path.append and path configuration files, but I'm not sure how to accomplish what I need to accomplish, or what the most pythonic way to do it is.

The biggest problem is I don't know how to specify "one directory up". Obviously this is `..`, but I'm not sure how to avoid this being interpreted as a string literal. For example if I do `sys.path.append('../')` it will literally append `../` to the path.

So my question is, what is the most "pythonic" way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is main.py doing? (Given no more info I would put main.py in the root of State_Editor and it would then work as you show)

Comment: I figured state_editor was supposed to hold the scripts (following a packaging guide I read in The Python Tutorial) I read earlier.

Comment: That'll definitely work though, and now that I'm looking around that seems pretty common. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In the question as stated, you need 2 leading dots (the module containing the import was state_editor.features.foobar).  So:

```
from ..io.fileop import SubInPath
```

Full docs:

http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement

Answer (score 1):

In recent-enough Python versions, "relative imports" as recommended by @fseto may be best (perhaps with a `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of your module).  For a solution compatible with a wide range of Python versions, e.g.,

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.pardir))
```

Comment: -1 Modifying sys.path within a library/module is a bad idea, as it could have unforeseen consequences on other modules. See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893598/pythonpath-vs-sys-path), for one example.