# Importing a user-made module that's folders away

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

So I'm trying to include a module that's a folder up from my python file and then multiple folders in.

So the folder hierarchy goes as:

```
\Folder\
    \Folder\First\
        \Folder\First\myPythonFile.py
    \Folder\Second\
        \Folder\Second\AnotherFolder\
            \Folder\Second\AnotherFolder\addedFile.py
```

I want to include the addedFile.py into my myPythonFile.py. I'm not sure how this is accomplished.

Comment: Is `Second` a python package? Is it something that should be added to a virtualenv or your PYTHONPATH so it's accessible from everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

relative imports are possible in Python since 2.5 (maybe 2.4)

if you add two empty `__init__.py` files in `Second` and `Second\AnotherFolder` folders, according to [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) you can write:

```
 from ..Second.AnotherFolder.addedFile import eggs
```

inside `myPythonFile.py`

to import the desired module (in my example *eggs*)

(adding `__init__.py` files inside your folders transforms them into *packages*)

**ALTERNATIVE APPROACH**

if you don't want to create packages for your `Second` folder you can alter your sys.path in order to include your `Second\AnotherFolder` folder:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../Second/AnotherFolder')))
import addedFile
```

but I discurage this approach, the reasons are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893598/pythonpath-vs-sys-path).