# how to add python path in mod_python

Tags: python, apache, mod-python

Hi I am using mod_python and I have a python module AA in a directory X and in directory X I have sub directories which has other modules which are imported in AA. I am importing AA in BB. when I run BB it fails to load modules imported in AA.

It's a python path issue, but the issue is how to dynamically set the path to the users workspace.

the workspace differs for each users.

Please help me on this.

to update I am using

```
sys. path.append(classpath)
```

in my BB script but still it fails.

my vhost file has following added in Directory tag :

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
PythonHandler mod_python
PythonDebug On
```

Comment: Does BB run ok in the shell?

Comment: Yes it works good from Shell when I run in browser it shows ImportError: No module named commentjson mod_python error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python path can be added using the PythonPath directive. It should work in the server, virtual host, directory and .htaccess contexts.

```
PythonPath "['/path/to/site1', '/path/to/site2']"
```

http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/directives.html#pythonpath

Comment: I am using sys.path.append(classpath) but still I see same issue

Comment: You have to post some code before I can try to help you. How are you appending path?  Also, take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893598/pythonpath-vs-sys-path

Comment: Thanks for the update I moved to swgi now itw working