# python 3.5 Flask install on apache 2.4

Tags: python, apache, flask, debian

I have Google Cloud with Debian 9. There are python 2.7a and 3.5. 3.5 I did as default.

I have apache where is PHP and I need to keep it there.
I installed `libapache2-mod-python` configured virtual host and pure python file return me a correct result.
I installed Flask framework and it throws an exception that `ImportError: No module named Flask`
It's my first time with Flask and in general with python in web.

For all examples I see mod_wsgi but I can't install it with libapache2-mod-python.

My questions are:
Does it's possible to run Flash with libapache2-mod-python module?
If no, then does mod_wsgi has no conflict with PHP apache module?
Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Yes it's possible to run both mod-python and php with the same apache server. The exception you get is a python exception, so python _is_ running. But you need to make sure the apache worker knows where to find your python modules. The apache worker has a different environment from your regular user, so you have to tell it where to find flask on the file system. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688306/how-to-add-python-path-in-mod-python

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you do not have flask installed. You may for example `pip install flask` to the particular python version that you are trying to run your flask app with.

Comment: I have installed Flask. I had to revert the default python to 2.7 because I had a problem with OS dependencies. Now all modules install/uninstall works.
Flask still doesn't work.
 Apache throw error that could not found webtool module for this code `from webtool import app as application` in .wsgi file.

For me, weird is a fact that `pip install flask` return info that `Requirement already satisfied: flask in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` probably apache use default 2.7.x

Comment: My virtual host config is ```<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  
  DocumentRoot /mypath
  WSGIDaemonProcess webtool threads=5 home=/mypath.com/
WSGIScriptAlias / /mypath/webtool.wsgi

  <Directory /mypath>
    WSGIProcessGroup webtool
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptReloading On

    Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

    DirectoryIndex index.py index.html index.html5
  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost> ```