# gitlab-ci.yml: 'script: -pytest cannot find any tests to check'

Tags: pytest, gitlab-ci

I'm having trouble implementing a toy example that runs pytest within .gitlab-ci.yml

**gitlab_ci** is a repo containing a single file `test_hello.py`

```
gitlab_ci/
    test_hello.py
```

**test_hello.py**

```py
# test_hello.py

import pytest

def hello():
    print("hello")

def hello_test():
    assert hello() == 'hello'
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml

pytest:
  image: python:3.6
  script:
    - apt-get update -q -y
    - pip install pytest
    - pytest # if this is removed, the job outputs 'Success'
```

**CI/CD terminal output**

```
$ pytest
=== test session starts ===
platform linux -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-5.2.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /builds/kunov/gitlab_ci
collected 0 items

=== no tests ran in 0.02s ===
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I'm not sure why the test did not run... pytest does not seem to recognize `test_hello.py`

---

**Solution**

Put the python file inside the newly creared **tests** folder:

```
gitlab_ci/
    .gitlab-ci.yml
    tests/
        test_hello.py
```

Modify **gitlab-ci.yml** in the following manner:

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml

pytest:
  image: python:3.6
  script:
  - apt-get update -q -y
  - pip install pytest
  - pwd
  - ls -l
  - export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:."
  - python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
  - pytest
```

And `test_hello.py` would stay the same as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [blog post](http://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-a-python-application/) mentions a similar pipeline, but:

> However, this did not work as pytest was unable to find the ‘bild’ module (ie. the source code) to test.
>   The problem encountered here is that the ‘bild’ module is not able to be found by the `test_*.py` files, as the top-level directory of the project was not being specified in the system path:

```
pytest:
  stage: Test
  script:
  - pwd
  - ls -l
  - export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:."
  - python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
  - pytest
```

The [OP kunov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12151746/kunov) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195130/gitlab-ci-yml-script-pytest-cannot-find-any-tests-to-check/58195220?noredirect=1#comment102769203_58195220):

> It works now! I put the single file inside a newly created folder called '`test`'

Answer (score 3):

Manipulation of the `PYTHONPATH` variable is considered by some to be a bad practice  (see e.g., [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894043/3162788) or this [Level Up Coding post](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/import-your-own-python-code-without-pythonpath-tricks-9068495c1bba)). While this is possible not a huge issue in the scope of a GitLab CI job, here is a solution without the need to fiddle with `PYTHONPATH` that is also somewhat cleaner. It is based on [Alberto Mardegan's comment on the blog post](http://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-a-python-application/) mentioned in [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58195220/3162788):

```
pytest:
  stage: Test
  script:
  - pwd
  - ls -l
  - python -m pytest
```

Why does this work? From the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/usage.html#calling-pytest-through-python-m-pytest):

> You can invoke testing through the Python interpreter from the command
> line:
>
> ```
> python -m pytest [...]
> ```
>
> This is almost equivalent to invoking the
> command line script `pytest [...]` directly, except that calling via
> `python` will also add the current directory to `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

## test_hello.py

def test_hello():#func name must start with "test_",not "hello_test"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).