# gitlab-ci.yml: 'script: -pytest' command is not recognized

Tags: python, gitlab, pytest, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm having trouble implementing an sample program that runs pytest within .gitlab-ci.yml on Windows:

**Using Shell executor...**

Please find below .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml

test_sample:
  stage: test
  tags: 
    - test_sam
  script:
    - echo "Testing"
    - pytest -s Target\tests 
  when: manual
```

CI/CD terminal output:

```
pytest is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

Python and pytest is already installed on the Windows OS on which the test is running but still the test fails.
I have tried the solution suggested in below thread but it doesn't work:
[gitlab-ci.yml: 'script: -pytest cannot find any tests to check'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195130/gitlab-ci-yml-script-pytest-cannot-find-any-tests-to-check)

Could you please suggest how to make this test pass on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below command worked without any issues:

```
py -m pytest -s Target\tests
```

Answer (score 3):

If `python` is recognized, you could replace `pytest`, as [with this similar project](https://git.soton.ac.uk/js22g12/AmpScan/-/blame/master/.gitlab-ci.yml), with:

```yaml
unittests:
  script: python -m unittest discover tests -v
core doctests:
  script: python -m doctest -v AmpScan/core.py
registration doctests:
  script: python -m doctest -v AmpScan/registration.py
align doctests:
  script: python -m doctest -v AmpScan/align.py
```

(The [initial switch to `pytest`](https://git.soton.ac.uk/js22g12/AmpScan/-/commit/f1d0e32a2da82a4e64df8aee6a0ff3244024424a) failed)

If you want to use pytest, you would need to use a python Docker image in your `.gitlab.yml`.

See "[Setting Up GitLab CI for a Python Application](https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-a-python-application/)" from [Patrick Kennedy](https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/sample-page/).

```yaml
image: "python:3.7"

before_script:
  - python --version
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

stages:
  - Static Analysis
  - Test
...
unit_test:
  stage: Test
  script:
  - pwd
  - ls -l
  - export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:."
  - python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
  - pytest
```

Comment: this does not work, I am getting error though I have installed python
$ python --version
 python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: Could you please suggest a working example because this solution is not specific to windows OS

Comment: $ py --version
Python 3.7.5

Comment: @user2077648 Double-check the %PATH% used by GitLab: it might not include the Python installation folder.