# How to add PATH to deal with this warning?

Tags: python, python-3.x

WARNING: The script pygmentize is installed in '/home/maulik/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux/Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/maulik/.local/bin')
```

You can check more on this here: [adding directory to sys.path /PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114391/adding-directory-to-sys-path-pythonpath) , [PYTHONPATH vs. sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893598/pythonpath-vs-sys-path) and [Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

Comment: I don't know if this answers the question cause I don't know the context, but `PATH` is certainly not the same thing as `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`.