# Cannot run jupyter (Mac M1 Max)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm on a Mac M1 Max running OS 12.5 and Python 3.10.4. I run `pip3 install jupyter` and the installation went fine but I get the warnings

> `WARNING: The script jupyter-console is installed in '/Users/userXYZ/Library/Python/3.10/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

Apparently I need to add `/Users/userXYZ/Library/Python/3.10/bin` to the PATH.

**Update** (after following the comment by @csgeek)

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70335223/how-to-add-path-to-deal-with-this-warning), in the python console I run

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/Users/userXYZ/Library/Python/3.10/bin')
```

The command run without visible output or errors, but when I type `jupyter-lab` in the terminal I get command not found. On the other hand, invoking the full path works:

```py
/Users/userXYZ/Library/Python/3.10/bin/jupyter-lab
```

Hence my questions:

1. How do I add to the PATH?
2. How do I check the contents of the PATH to see if it is updated?
3. I am running from an account without administrative privileges. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Check if python is installed on your mac, and make sure you are running the `import sys` command in python console.

Comment: @csgeek My mistake was running `import sys`  on the terminal console. I run the commands on the console and they were executed silently. Still, running `jupyter-lab` gives command not found. On the other hand I can run jupyter if I use `/Users/userXYZ/Library/Python/3.10/bin/jupyter-lab`. Apparently I am missing something.

Comment: I don't use Mac, but this looks correct: [Right way to add paths to PATH in mojave - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/358687/282701). (I found a bunch of other pages too, including some existing questions here on SO, but they left out crucial info for a beginner.)

Answer (score 0):

First, I should say that since my original question I reinstalled `jupyter`, this time using homebrew. I am on zsh, so I created the file `.zshrc` and added the line

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin"
```

'echo $PATH` now shows

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/homebrew/bin
```

and `jupyter notebook` runs as expected.

For bash shell I suppose the process is as described in the [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358687/right-way-to-add-paths-to-path-in-mojave) by @wjandrea