# How to make it possible to make global imports starting from a source root?

Tags: python, import

I guess my question is a duplicate, but, unfortunately, I haven't found a solution that corresponds to my problem.

I have following project structure:

```
↓ project_root
  ↓ source_root
      __init__.py
    ↓ inner_package
        some_executable_file.py
        some_library_file.py
```

So I would like to import a name from 'some_library_file' in the following way:

```
from source_root.inner_package.some_library_file import X
```

But when I do something like this, I see the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'source_root'
```

Comment: Where do you have the script with the import and where do you run it from?

Comment: Update `sys.path` so the first element in the list is your project root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install your own project to your (ideally virtual) environment. In order to do this, you need a `setup.py` file, which will be used by `pip` to find all your packages (i.e., folders containing `__init__.py`) during installation.

Minimal example:

`project_root/setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='MyProjectName',
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

Then from the command line, `cd` into your `project_root` ant type:

```
python -m pip install -e .
```

You now installed your own project into your Python environment. Files in the project are able to import their own packages with the `from source_root.[...] import [...]` syntax.

This process mimics a user `pip install`ing your project from PyPI / github, so you can be sure that your imports are going to work on any other environment/machines, provided `pip` is used for installation.

The `-e` flag is used to install the project in [editable mode](https://pip-python3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#editable-installs), so you won't need to reinstall the package locally after changing one of the source files (which you'll be doing a lot during development).

Comment: Are you saying you always need to install your project to be able to import your own modules?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych that's certainly not the only way, but it's the best way I've found in order to keep things consistent across multiple machines and environments. Other solutions tend to include `sys.path / PYTHONPATH` hacking, and may or may not work depending on the environment specifics (i.e. what's the current working directory, whether you're running the script from a terminal vs VS Code vs PyCharm, ...). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1893622/11161432